# make code execute when x starts with y

Tags: java, android, if-statement, arraylist

First of all, I apologize for this unclear title!

So I am making an app, and I have an `if statement` :

```
 if(num.contains(input) )
 {
      ...
 }
```

So, say `num` is `213`, and  `input` is `1`, it will still execute the the block inside the `statement.`
But I want to make an `if statement` that only executes when `num` starts with `input`, and the other characters after 1 don't matter.

Note: 
All variables are `Strings`

Comment: What is `num`? A `string`?

Comment: Maybe convert it to a string and check the first character?

Comment: @unlimit yes, all the variables are strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use startsWith()

num.startsWith(input)

Here is something for your reference :-
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_startswith.htm

Answer (score 0):

maybe convert it to a string and see if the index of input is in the string at the very front.

```
if(String.valueOf(num).indexOf(String.valueOf(input))==0){
//do stuff
}
```

edit:

If the variables are strings you can just check the index of input in num

```
if(num.indexOf(input)==0){
//do stuff
}
```